# How does OWASP rank the top 10 risks?

Tags: owasp, owasp-top-ten

I was reading articles about OWASP A2 (2017) and the found below comparison chart. One thing I noticed was that "Broken Account and Session Management" has changed place over the years:

- In 2003 and 2004 it was **A3**.
- In 2007 it was **A7**.
- In 2010 it was **A3**.
- In 2013 and 2017 it is **A2**.

What is the reason for this?

[image: Comparison of OWASP rankings over the years.]

(Original source from which the image was generated is unknown.  Google reverse image search https://images.app.goo.gl/haEq2nxGjKYzgWrR9 shows that a more complete image that includes footnotes is at https://goldcrock.wordpress.com/2015/02/ - but it's unclear where that was originally sourced.)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that they are rated on the prevalence of that specific risk in the wild.

This is explained in the introduction to OWASP top 10 [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Introduction)

> Welcome to the OWASP Top 10...r**eorders some of the others based on
>   changing prevalence data.**

So A1 is more common in the wild than A2 and so on.